# http0.0000000.000000www .. On Wordpress Log Out Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create a logout link which redirect to home url. I've tried this function:

`wp_logout_url(site_url)`

but, the output resulting strange prefix.

`http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http0.0000000.000000www.example.com&_wpnonce=f2c0bef0b0`

then I trying to hardcode the `site_url()`, but that prefix still exist and redirecting to wrong url.

How to solve it?

Thanks,

Wildan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to put `urldecode()` function. don't know why. So, it'll look like:

`urldecode(wp_logout_url(site_url))`